# Keep a (longer) session with every Web Application that has an inactivity timeout

Tags: javascript, session, iframe, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am using a proxy that allowed me to get a free internet from my mobile company

the problem is 
some times I have to send so many request to a web application to finally get 
200 ok http response

see this picture for more illustration 
[successful requests are in black and a failed request are in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r85qF.jpg)

to keep a longer session with a certain web application i have to reload it every five minutes or so

so is there any other solution rather than reloading the web page to maintain a longer session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an html file, change url that you want to open in iframe, save and open in browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" >

<body>

<iframe src="http://yourwebsite.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i was wrong 
you are brilliant Thank you , I just have to add all website that I want to maintain session with in html file

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without Javascript, with metatag.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```

Comment: its not my own web application
so how can  i use this code inside a web page ??